# Getting no response on Zoho API CRM

Tags: php, zoho

I am trying to use getSearchRecordsByPDC method which can be found here https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/getsearchrecordsbypdc.html#Request_URL

I have this code:

```
private $token = '1234567890abcdefg';
public $responseType = 'xml';

 public function getSearchRecordsByPDC($searchValue,$searchColumn='email')
 {
 $url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/".$this->responseType."/Leads/getSearchRecordsByPDC?newFormat=1&authtoken=".$this->token."&scope=crmapi&selectColumns=Leads(First Name,Lead Source,Phone,Mobile,Website,Lead Status,Description,Last Name,Website,Email,Lead Owner)&searchColumn=$searchColumn&searchValue=$searchValue";

 $result = $this->curlRequest($url);
 return $result;
 }

 public function curlRequest($url)
 {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $output;
 }

$data = $zoho->getSearchRecordsByPDC('my_email@gmail.com');
print_r($data);
```

I just posted some snippets of my code to not appear it to be very long.

When running this code. I am not getting any response, even an error message or whatsoever, like I am getting a blank response, no xml response or whatever. But when ever I try to copy and paste the `$url` variable output into my web browser, I am getting response, and those response are valid.

What's wrong with this? Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing up OOP and procedural code. Try this:

```
class Zoho {
    private $token = '1234567890abcdefg';
    public $responseType = 'xml';

    public function getSearchRecordsByPDC($searchValue,$searchColumn='email')
    {
        $url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/".$this->responseType."/Leads/getSearchRecordsByPDC?newFormat=1&authtoken=".$this->token."&scope=crmapi&selectColumns=Leads(First Name,Lead Source,Phone,Mobile,Website,Lead Status,Description,Last Name,Website,Email,Lead Owner)&searchColumn=$searchColumn&searchValue=$searchValue";

        $result = $this->curlRequest($url);
        return $result;
    }

    public function curlRequest($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
}

$zoho = new Zoho;
$data = $zoho->getSearchRecordsByPDC('my_email@gmail.com');
print_r($data);
```